# Can I use more slicing lines with UIImage?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, nine-patch, cashapelayer

I want to change rectangle proportions dynamically but preserving semicircle's proportions. Semicircle should be aligned to the bottom and centered horizontally:

[image]

How can I add more slicing lines to UIImage in Xcode?

I have made what I want in Nine Patch editor for android, but it isn't compatible with iOS.

[image]

Comment: Or how to implement it programmatically?

Comment: pls don't tag questions  with android tag , unless they have anything to do with android , which yours isnt .

Comment: There is no way to stretch an image like you want so you should do it programmatically with CAShapeLayer. Do you prefer swift or obj-c?

Comment: I prefer swift, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stretch UIImage like you want, but you can do it programmatically. I've implemented a custom UIView with **CAShapeLayer** inside:

```
import UIKit

class CustomShapeView: UIView {

    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var radius = CGFloat(0)
    var shadowRadius = CGFloat(5)

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.path = createShapePath().cgPath

        shapeLayer.shadowPath = shapeLayer.path
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func createShapePath () -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let w = self.bounds.size.width
        let h = self.bounds.size.height
        let circleLever: CGFloat = radius * 0.552

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w/2 - radius, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w/2 + radius, y: h))

        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: w/2, y: h - radius), controlPoint1:CGPoint(x: w/2 + radius, y: h - circleLever), controlPoint2:CGPoint(x: w/2 + circleLever, y: h - radius))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: w/2 - radius, y: h), controlPoint1:CGPoint(x: w/2 - circleLever, y: h - radius), controlPoint2:CGPoint(x: w/2 - radius, y: h - circleLever))
        path.close()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w/2 - radius, y: h))

        return path
    }        
}
```

You can set whatever size and any radius you want, circle's center will always be on the bottom edge of the view. You also can change `shadowRadius` if you wish.

**Setup in Interface Builder:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]